# RE: 275 record limit for $search in Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api, outlook-restapi

We have been hoping to use Graph API's $search capability (i.e. received>05/06/2020) to find Outlook messages but it seems the search result is limited to 275 records. Is that a known limitation? Why is there skipToken then if there is no way to receive all matching records?

Using $filter (i.e. ReceivedDateTime gt 2020-05-06) does return all matching messages but there is no $filter way to find emails by matching To or Cc.

Thank you

Comment: Another problem is that "to:emailAddress" does not find anything for the mailbox's own email address. I connect to this mailbox using EWS and the same AQS finds many messages. How do you explain this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You can search messages based on a value in specific message properties. The results of the search are sorted by the date and time that the message was sent. **A `$search` request returns up to 250 results.**

As the [official article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/query-parameters#search-parameter) said, A `$search` request returns **up to 250 results**. So it is a limit for $search in graph api.

For [`skipToken`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/query-parameters#skiptoken-parameter)：

> Some requests return multiple pages of data either due to server-side paging or due to the use of the `$top` parameter to limit the page size of the response. Many Microsoft Graph APIs use the `skipToken` query parameter to reference subsequent pages of the result.

Comment: Any plans to address this limitation and let us page through all matching records?
By the is $search essentially implemented using Exchange's AQS? Thank you.

Comment: It  seems that you can give your [voice](https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests) to this platform and product group will see your feedback.

Comment: Is there any way to find emails To/Cc'ing certain emails using $filter instead of $search?

Comment: Our main issue is really with searching for recipients/participants. These queries can't be rewritten using $filter.

Answer (score 1):

One possibility would be to start the $search as you have done. If the $search returns more than 250 results you check the datetime of the oldest message. Then repeat the search again with  received>05/06/2020 AND received<{datetime of the oldest message}
Not a very smart solution - because we have to request the api again and again, which produces more trafic on server. But if there is currently no alternative solution.